# Send recaptcha response through REST client

Tags: postman, recaptcha, insomnia

Are there any ways to pass recaptcha response token through API request as header value using Insomnia or Postman clients?

I know that response token is generated after recaptcha widget is loaded and user 
 interacted with it. And response token is being refreshed after each time module is loaded.

Maybe there are some addons for these REST clients which can generate response token based on public recaptcha key? Or other REST clients which have these feature.

P. S. Now I have to comment block of code which is responsible about server-side recaptcha validation.

---

Update: are there any other ways to test such API endpoint?